# Book about a girl who discovers powers while dancing

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book about a girl who discovered she had powers when she was a kid while she was dancing she started to float. When she goes to college she meets an Irish exchange student and falls in love. She goes with him to study abroad in Ireland and finds out he is bad. She meets a fairy (named Clay?) and finds this whole fairy compound.

Comment: I've roll backed your roll back because the edited version is objectively better per our standards here. It is correctly tagged, has a better, more descriptive title and fixes what appear to be a few grammar/spelling mistakes. If there is anything in this version of the post you want to change you can [edit] to fix those rather than reverting the whole thing.